# How MKI$ and CVI Functions works

Tags: gw-basic

I am working on GwBasic and want to know how 'CVI("aa")' returns '24929' is that converts each char to ASCII but code of "aa" is 9797.

Comment: Why don't you see what `CVI("a")` returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CVI` converts between a GW-BASIC integer and its internal representation in bytes. That internal representation is a 16-bit little-endian signed integer, so that the value you find is the same as `ASC("a") + 256*ASC("a")`, which is `97 + 256*97`, which is `24929`.

`MKI$` is the opposite operation of `CVI`, so that `MKI$(24929)` returns the string `"aa"`.

The 'byte reversal' is a consequence of the little endianness of GW-BASIC's internal representation of integers: the leftmost byte of the representation is the *least* significant byte, whereas in hexadecimal notation you would write the *most* significant byte on the left.